# How to solve issue in loading Angular app, after service is injected to the component?

Tags: angular, service, components

This is my sample code . Here after i injected **OrderDetailService** to the constructor of **home.component.ts**  my app is not loading and browser is hanging by throwing this error :
I have gone through different solutions from stack itself but my issue is not solved yet . Can anyone please help.

`common.js:167 Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/882238. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection`

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { OrderDetailService } from '../../services/order-detail.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [OrderDetailService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  searchCriteria: any = {};
  orderDetailResultForView = [];
  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private orderDetails: OrderDetailService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**order-detail.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
   import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
   import { BaseUrlService } from './base-url.service';
   @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
  export class OrderDetailService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private basicUrl: BaseUrlService) { }
  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

   import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
   import { BaseUrlService } from './services//base-url.service';
   import { OrderDetailService } from './services/order-detail.service';

   @NgModule({
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
   ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [OrderDetailService,BaseUrlService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `OrderDetailService` on your `AppModule` and `HomeComponent`.

This is because you have specified in your `Injectable` to be
`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` which this is by default be loaded on the root of your app.

**Service**

As per the **[Angular Dependency Injection Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#configure-an-injector-with-a-service-provider)**

Below, will declare that this service should be created by the **root** application injector.

> Angular creates injectors for you as it executes the app, starting with the root injector that it creates during the bootstrap process.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',               
})
export class OrderDetailService { ...}
```

---

You should update yours to just be

**Component**

```
import { OrderDetailService } from '../../services/order-detail.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

   // You can use it directly
   constructor(private orderDetails: OrderDetailService) { }

}
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
    ...,
    providers: [BaseUrlService],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit struggling with your component decorator in your home.component.ts:

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
      providers: [OrderDetailService] => I would remove this line
    })
```

In my project's I do not declare providers inside component's decorator. I would remove the line for provider's there.

2nd thing:
As I can see you use http, so you may need to import any services inside your app.module.ts, like HttpClientModule (this is what I need to import, to get use of http service in Angular10).